# SpringBoot/Hibernate triggers update queries from find repository method under a readonly transaction due to entities dirtiness checking

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I got a non-`@Transactional` test method which executes a read-only `@Transactional` service.

When the service is executing a repository.findX operation, it throws an error

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: cannot execute UPDATE in a read-only transaction

When debugging, I see the error query. Looks like Hibernate flushes before the execution of my finder, and then to identify whether the entity is "Dirty" or not, depending on certain strategy, it simply refreshes the underlying entity by doing an update with all fields in memory

How can I make sure that no write operation is pending before I enter into a `@Transactional`(readonly)??

Answer (score 2):

If `default_transaction_read_only` is set to on, you can either start a read-write transaction with `START TRANSACTION READ WRITE;`

or change the setting by editing `postgresql.conf` or with the superuser command

```
ALTER SYSTEM SET default_transaction_read_only = off;
```

Comment: The problem is that I want to disallow non-read queries but I dont understand why is Hibernate/Spring issuing flushes which trigger updates within a read-only transaction